# CMake dependencies on included files

Tags: cmake, flex-lexer

From the question [Defining lex include files for (f)lexers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197941/defining-lex-include-files-for-flexers) we are already knowing that there is no lex distribution known that has an include file facility for e.g. rules into a lex file.

The suggestion there was to write an own pre-processor.

When defining an own pre-processor one generates, of course, dependencies on the included file(s), so when such a file is changed one wants to do a rebuild of the "lex" file.
With C / C++ the dependencies are handled (to the best of my knowledge) automatically (probably by some CMake script).

- How to accomplish the dependency rules for the file(s) included in a lex file?

**Edit**

Say I have an original `.l` file `configimpl.l` that includes the files `aa.inc` and `bb.inc`, by converting the original `.l` file (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l`) by means of a python script into a new `.l` (`${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l`) file (and we also have an output file `${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.corr` but that is not relevant here).
Of course all "cmake" variables etc. have been set properly.

My code for the preprocessing (i.e. including the include files into the `.l` file) is:

```
    add_custom_command(
        COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pre_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.corr ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pre_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l ${LEX_INC_FILES}
        OUTPUT  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.corr ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l
    )
```

and this works fine, except when the `aa.inc` or the `bb.inc` changes the "generated included" `${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l` is not rebuild.

Based on the question: [Dynamic dependency within custom source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713117/dynamic-dependency-within-custom-source-files) I already tried to create something, but failed.

```
    add_custom_command(
        COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dep_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dep_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l
        OUTPUT  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d
    )
    set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)
    add_custom_command(
        COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pre_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.corr ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pre_lex.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${lex_file}.l
        DEPFILE ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d
        OUTPUT  ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.corr
    )
```

So I first run a dependency detection step that creates a file `${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d` with as content:

```
${GENERATED_SRC}/generated_src/configimpl.l: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/aa.inc
${GENERATED_SRC}/generated_src/configimpl.l: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bb.inc
```

in this generated file the paths are, of course, set to the full paths.
After this the original preprocessing step is run but now with the extra `DEPFILE ${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.d` that should signal that there are some extra dependencies.

When I change the `aa.inc` or the `bb.inc` the `${GENERATED_SRC}/${lex_file}.l` is not rebuild, what did I miss?

Used CMake version: cmake version 3.22.1
used generator: NMake Makefiles

Comment: Such long lines, they could use newlines. `Say I have an original .l file` I do not understand the sentence. What is the input, what is the output, and what is going on. `what did I miss?` DEPFILE is a byproduct of the command, not a separate stage. _One_ command, generates the output file _and_ at the same time generates the DEPFILE. I can only throw you at my M4 adventure: https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/master/cmake/k/m4.sh#L11 and https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/master/cmake/k/m4.cmake#L93 .

Comment: `is not rebuild, what did I miss?` I do not understand, but there can't be any `${GENERATED_SRC}` variable expansions in depfile, and at best, it's best to keep all paths absolute. Also, it's best, at least to my experience with Make and Ninja, to have _one line_. Make it one long line. (I remember some parser using a hashmap and overwriting the previous entry)

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the comment the `{GENERATED_SRC}` is expanded but the part `Also, it's best, at least to my experience with Make and Ninja, to have one line.` looks like to be the solution. I tried it, quickly, manually in my `.d` file and this looks like to work!! Now I have to implement this in my `dep_lex.py` script.:w

Comment: @KamilCuk I just tested with my `dep_lex.py` file and the `one line` approach works, can you make an answer out of it? (and maybe also add this information to to your original answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62713715/1657886, it is implied here but when it is more explicit ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the DEPFILE output as one long line, then it works the best. From memory, I *think* the parser for the depfile is not smart enough to handle multiple lines. When in doubt - see the output of `-MT -MD` of gcc, the format should be the same.